# how to read complex XML

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, linq-to-xml

I have got the following XML

```
    <departments>
      <dept operationalStatus="active" primaryRole="Admin" depChangeDate="20130420">        
        <startDate type="legal">20130401</startDate>
        <endDate type="legal"></endDate>
        <startDate type="operational">20130320</startDate>
        <endDate type="operational"></endDate>  
      <DeptRoles>           
        <DeptRole name="Other dept" status="active">
            <startDate type="legal">20130401</startDate>
            <endDate type="legal"></endDate>
            <startDate type="operational">20130320</startDate>
            <endDate type="operational"/>
            <isPrimary/>                
        </DeptRole>
      </DeptRoles>
    </dept>
   </departments>
```

i have got about 200K records to upload to database from xml file. i would like to get data the following data from xml file in one table 
operationalStatus, primaryRole, depChangeDate, startDate type legal and its value and  startDate type operational and its value
i can access upto the startDate type legal element but can't access startDate type operational.
and the following data from DeptRole element into another table.
DeptRole name, status, startDate type legal and its value and  startDate type operational and its value.
What is the best approach and how can i do this.
Mainly i am facing problem with accessing the following values

```
    <startDate type="legal">20130401</startDate>
<endDate type="legal"></endDate>
<startDate type="operational">20130320</startDate>
<endDate type="operational"></endDate>
```

Comment: How have you tried to access those values?

Comment: @DanielKelley by if (el.Element("startDate").Attribute("type").ToString() == "legal"

Comment: @DanielKelley if (el.Element("startDate").Attribute("type").ToString() == "operational"

Comment: @DanielKelley legal value is successful but operational if statement is never true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this help?

```
string data = "<your xml data>";
XElement elem = XElement.Parse(data);

var departments = elem.Descendants("dept").ToList();
foreach (var dept in departments)
{
    var sLegal = dept.Elements("startDate")
            .First(p => p.Attribute("type").Value == "legal").Value;
    var eLegal = dept.Elements("endDate")
            .First(p => p.Attribute("type").Value == "legal").Value;
    var sOp = dept.Elements("startDate")
            .First(p => p.Attribute("type").Value == "operational").Value;
    var eOp = dept.Elements("endDate")
            .First(p => p.Attribute("type").Value == "operational").Value;
    var attr=dept.Attribute("operationalStatus");
    var opStatus = attr == null ? "" : attr.Value;                
    attr = dept.Attribute("primaryRole");
    var primaryRole = attr == null ? "" : attr.Value;                
    attr = dept.Attribute("depChangeDate");
    var depChangeDate = attr == null ? "" : attr.Value;
    //do something with the values
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that help but how do i add the rest of the attributes operationalStatus, primaryRole, depChangeDate

Comment: Thanks muchly for your help. how do i validate the element or the attribute if they are present in the data. e.g <isPrimary/> how do i check if it's present. As this is not present in all records. and attribute e.g operationalStatus in the dept element. please help me with this....

Comment: use dept.Element("<name>") or dept.Attribute("<name>"). if they are null than they are missing.
the last lines of code do this for attributes

Answer (score 1):

Several options are available, however you will like this one:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2013/09/27/web-essentials-for-visual-studio-open-data-made-simple.aspx

It allows you to 'Copy' the xml and then 'Paste' a c# class. Serializing or deserializing will result in the xml that you used to generate that class.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by following ways

1. Convert your XML as DataSet() object and apply LINQ to fetch required columns
   (or)
2. Apply XPATH on XMLDocument

--SJ

Comment: [Apply XPATH on XMLDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("PurchaseOrder.xml")
Xdocument is a class from the System.Linq namespace so from this point there are ways to access it via LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

It will work...

```
  var readAll = from a in xd.Descendants("departments")


                      select new
                      {
                          DeptOperationalStatus = a.Element("dept").Attribute("operationalStatus").Value,
                          DeptPrimaryRole = a.Element("dept").Attribute("primaryRole").Value,
                          DeptChangeDate = a.Element("dept").Attribute("depChangeDate").Value,

                          LegalStartDate = a.Element("dept").Elements("startDate").First(cc => cc.Attribute("type").Value == "legal").Value,
                          LegalEndDate = a.Element("dept").Elements("endDate").First(cc => cc.Attribute("type").Value == "legal").Value,

                          OperationalStartDate = a.Element("dept").Elements("startDate").First(cc => cc.Attribute("type").Value == "operational").Value,
                          OperationEndDate = a.Elements("dept").Elements("endDate").First(cc => cc.Attribute("type").Value == "operational").Value,

                          // Dept Roles

                          DeptRoleName = a.Element("dept").Element("DeptRoles").Element("DeptRole").Attribute("name").Value,
                          DeptRoleStatus = a.Element("dept").Element("DeptRoles").Element("DeptRole").Attribute("status").Value,

                          DeptLegalStartDate = a.Element("dept").Element("DeptRoles").Element("DeptRole").Elements("startDate").First(cc => cc.Attribute("type").Value == "legal").Value,
                          DeptLegalEndDate = a.Element("dept").Element("DeptRoles").Element("DeptRole").Elements("endDate").First(cc => cc.Attribute("type").Value == "legal").Value,

                          DeptOperationalStartDate = a.Element("dept").Element("DeptRoles").Element("DeptRole").Elements("startDate").First(cc => cc.Attribute("type").Value == "operational").Value,
                          DeptOperationalEndDate = a.Element("dept").Element("DeptRoles").Element("DeptRole").Elements("endDate").First(cc => cc.Attribute("type").Value == "operational").Value,



                      };
```